# How to change build directory in scons by using renesas compiler

Tags: scons

I am using scons script to compile my code by using VC10 and renesas compiler.

i am successfully building my source code in variant directory by using VC10, But if i used the same script for the renesas compiler it is not building the obj files in variant directory.
can anyone tell me how to do that.

I am using renesas rx600 family controller.

My example tree look like

```
src1
    -main.c
   sconscript
   sconstruct
   subdirA
      fileA.c
      sconscript
   subdirB
      fileB.c
      sconscript
```

src1/sconstruct contains

```
import os

env = Environment()
tmp_obj_list = []

env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})

env['LINKFLAGS'] = "/nologo /subsystem:console /pdb:project.pdb"
env['CCFLAGS'] = "/nologo /wd4355 /GR- /EHs-c- /MT /c /W3 /WX /Zi /FD"
env['ENV']['TMP'] = os.environ['TMP']
env['ENV']['TEMP'] = os.environ['TEMP']

Export('env')

env.SConscript('d://src1//subdirA//SConscript',
               variant_dir = 'd://build1//subdirA', 
               duplicate = 0, exports = 'env')
tmp_obj_list.append(Glob('d://build1//subdirA' + '/*.lib'))
env.SConscript('d://src1//subdirB//SConscript',
               variant_dir = 'd://build1//subdirB',
               duplicate = 0, exports = 'env')
tmp_obj_list.append(Glob('d://build1//subdirB' + '/*.lib'))

env.SConscript('d://src1//SConscript')
env.Append(LIBS = tmp_obj_list)
```

src1/sconscript contains

```
Import('env')

env.Program('program',Glob('*.c'))
env.Clean('program','d://build1')
```

src1/subdirA & src1/subdirB sconscript contains

```
Import('env')
l = env.Library(target='subdirB', source='fileB.c')

Return('l')
```

Comment: The compiler shouldnt matter, its all about the SConscript. Can you show us your scripts?

Comment: Hi bray..
i have modified the script
it is compiling...but I have one doubt.
To run the executable file in my compiler i neer .abs file. But Program() function generating .exe file
How to modify this
can you please help me.
and am adding my example to my original question
thank you

Comment: It would be helpful to see what the output is when you build it. Is it building into the source directories and not into the variant dir?